# How to string replace and swap between 2 characters to replace with

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me explain what I mean by the title (couldn't think of a better way to word it, sorry!)

How would I do a string replace, where it would replace all instances of a character in an array, but cycle between what I replace it with swapping from `x` to `y`.

For example, if I had a string that looked like this `hello....`, how would I run a string replace, and replace all the odd number characters with `!` and even number characters with `?` so my string looked like this `hello!?!?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a string for replacement where the index toggels between zero and one.

```js
var string = 'hello....';
    
console.log(string.replace(/\./g, (i => _ => '!?'[i = 1 - i])(1)));
```

With an object.

```js
var string = 'hello....';
    
console.log(string.replace(/\./g, (v => _ => v = { '!': '?', '?': '!' }[v])('?')));
```

Comment: Brilliant, sorry to be a pain but could you briefly explain how this works? The code works great, but i've no idea how it does it.

Comment: Very much to the point! Although maybe a few words of explanation might be appreciated. ;-)

Comment: @S_R Nina uses an IIFE to return an unnamed function as a second argument to the `replace()` method. The argument i of the IIFE is given the value 1 and is used as an outside-defined-variable within the returned unnamed function. The value of i is toggled between 0 and 1 each time the unnamed function is called by the string method `replace()`. This in turn causes a different replacement character ('?' and '!') to be returned as a replacement string. And the argument `_` of the unnamed function is just a dummy argument. You could use `()` ( an empty argument) list instead.

Comment: S_R, sorry, had to go to bed, but the explanateion of @cars10m is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Give the replace function another function as an argument:

```js
const getSwitchChar = (() => {
  let currentChar = 'b';
  return () => {
    if (currentChar === 'a') currentChar = 'b';
    else currentChar = 'a';
    return currentChar;
  };
})();

function switchReplace(str) {
  return str.replace(/e/g, getSwitchChar);
}
console.log(switchReplace('zzzeeeezzz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function as the second argument to `replace`. With each replacement, increment the symbol with `replaceIndex` (modulo the number of symbols):

```js
const pattern = /[.]/g, // Matches each dot
  replaceWith = ["?", "!"];
let replaceIndex = 0;

console.log("hello....".replace(pattern, (dot) => (replaceIndex = (replaceIndex + 1) % replaceWith.length, replaceWith[replaceIndex])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `let s = "hello....";`

Then you can do:

```js
let s = "hello....";
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
 if(s[i] == ".") // or your pattern here
    s = s.substr(0, i) + ((i % 2 == 0)? "?" : "!") + s.substr(i + 1);
}
console.log(s);
```

You can iterate through strings. So you can do a check for your character and replace the variable woth your modified string.